# Where exactly on USPTO site should I look for reexamination process details?

Tags: uspto, reexamination, pair

[Here's just one example](https://patents.stackexchange.com/q/3615/962) - a question about whether some patent was invalidated during reexamination. [This answer](https://patents.stackexchange.com/a/3618/962) says

> This can be looked up and followed in the USPTO Public PAIR

Now I go to http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair and "search by patent number" and there's lots of data on multiple tabs.

Where's the data on reexamination in there?

Comment: look at continuity data tab. The SE link(answer) you gave also talks about the details of reexamination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you take a look at [How does one know if a patent was reexamined?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/4893/how-does-one-know-if-a-patent-was-reexamined)

All your answers with graphical illustrations are there.